# Android - Scrollview don't push up when keyboard appear

Tags: android, scrollview

My app have an activity with layuot like this

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundchatfixed">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/layoutKhungChat"
        android:id="@+id/svChat">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/layoutChat">

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/background_khungchat"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/layoutKhungChat">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/khungchat_chat"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:id="@+id/etChatbox"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When i touch my Edittext, only layout "layoutKungChat" push up.
Any solution to push up also Scrollview above it?
Thanks.

Comment: show some snap what happening.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to the activity tag in the manifest:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/layoutMain"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/backgroundchatfixed">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background_khungchat"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/layoutKhungChat">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/khungchat_chat"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:id="@+id/etChatbox"/>

</RelativeLayout>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/layoutKhungChat"
    android:id="@+id/svChat">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/layoutChat">

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

the one in the last always be written over the other layouts so if you want like buttons to be above an image layout as an example write it inside of layout below the image